# No acces to applications

Tags: unity, virtualbox

I am trying Ubuntu and installed it in a Virtualbox under Windows 8.1. Everything seems to work fine, however in the upper left corner of the window "Applications", "Places", "System" and the like are missing, so I have no access to programs (except the ones on a bar left in the window). The only thing I see is "Ubuntu Desktop". What can be wrong or did I miss?

[image: View of the upper left side of the desktop]

Comment: But the image you posted here,I can see everything you are mentioning are available here.

Comment: @saptarshinag he's missing the panel menu from GNOME2.

Comment: Oh!I see.It's unity,things are more advanced and easily explorable.I think he should take a tour from 'Dash' and 'Nautilus' to get accustomed with it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These buttons exist in GNOME2, the old desktop environment of Ubuntu. Some years ago, Ubuntu got its own DE called Unity.

To access the features you were talking about, hit the Ubuntu logo at the top right and select the according tab ("lens") at the bottom of the menu ("Dash") that opens.

You can learn more about Unity here: https://unity.ubuntu.com/about/

PS: The menu of an open window can be found where you read "Ubuntu Desktop" when you move your mouse to the panel.

---

If you prefer something like GNOME2, you should install MATE, a fork of GNOME2, which aim it is to provide exactly the same thing as GNOME2 did, but is still being developed today.

If you want to use MATE, either just use the Ubuntu derivate https://ubuntu-mate.org/
or follow these steps to install mate on your running system:

1. Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Add the MATE PPA's:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
3. Install MATE:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
   ```
4. Reboot your computer
5. Before logging in, select MATE in the session chooser (click the Ubuntu logo you see in the picture):

[image]

6. Log in to your MATE session.

Comment: "the old desktop environment of Ubuntu". I just downloaded the most recent version of Ubuntu. How could the desktop be 'old'?

Comment: What you're seeing is the NEW one, Unity. The OLD one, GNOME, is the one with the featuresyou're missing.

Comment: OK, I understand that Ubuntu 14.04 comes with Unity, a relative new desktop environment, which does not have the features I mentioned. Via "Ubuntu Desktop Guide" I understand that from the Dash I can add application icons to the Launcher. Mmm, leaving out the Applications menu seems not very handy to me. Anyway, it's clear now what's going on. However, I have no Ubuntu logo in my login window

Comment: If you don't like it, install MATE, as I suggested.

Comment: I followed your instructions, MATE seems installed, but when I login I still get the Unity desktop.

Comment: OK, I found a button in the right side of the screen with which I can choose between Ubuntu and MATE (session chooser?